# Is it possible to route an old AngularJS page with a new Angular router?

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-router

We are migrating an application where we have old(AngularJS) and new(Angular 8) components. They are complex and so we want to migrate them step by step. My question is if it is possible to add a route to my "new" router which redirects to an old AngularJS component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ngUpgrade` to run Angular + AngularJS until you fully migrated, but you will need some changes in the AnguleJS too components.

You can check the official documentation [here](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade#upgrading-with-ngupgrade).

Comment: Is there also a 'cheap' way to solve my problem? Maybe declare my route as an old AngularJS one?

Comment: No I don't think so AFAIK

Comment: Ok thx. We will try to achieve this with you given documention

Answer (score 1):

Better you rewrite the old AngularJS component for the new Angular 8 project so that you don't get to face scalability issues in future.
[coryrylan.com/blog — AngularComparing Angular 1 Components to the latest Angular Components](https://coryrylan.com/blog/comparing-angular-1-components-to-the-latest-angular-components) is the link that compares old vs new component structure

Comment: We will do that but only step by step.

Answer (score 0):

no, you can not used angular Route direct on your application. you need to upgrade version.